# Assigning a local variable from a table using a join statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, join

I'm working with SQL, and I can't seem to figure this out for the life of me.

I have a local variable in my stored procedure called `@curType`.  I have two tables, DTXR and DP.  DP contains the columns `type` and `programID`.  DTXR contains the columns `programID` and `QEI`.  The stored procedure is passed the `QEI`, and I need to get the `type` from the table DP and assign it to the local variable `@curType`.

So, I currently have

```
select @curType = [Type] From DP d 
       Join DTXR x on d.ProgramId = x.ProgramID
       where x.QEI = @p_QEI.
```

@p_QEI is the variable passed into the stored procedure.

The problem I'm running in to is this doesn't seem to set @curType.  It works if I manually set the program id like this:

```
select @curType = [Type] from DP Where DP.ProgramId = 120
```

But the join statement seems to be setting @curType to null.

Comment: Are you sure there is only one record min DP that matches the record on dtxr?  I believe the value of @curType will be the first record that it encounters which may not be the record that you expect it to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, this should work. I would check to make sure that the following even returns anything at all (and if it does, what is the first result back?):

```
   select [Type] From DP d 
   Join DTXR x on d.ProgramId = x.ProgramID
   where dtxr.QEI = @p_QEI
```

That should be the problem, as [here is a fiddle proving that a join does nothing different](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d53e2/2)

Comment: That's one of the first things I checked and I get exactly what I expect.  The data is there.  The select statement works.  But assigning that to the local variable doesn't seem to play nice.

Comment: @CurtisHx I just updated my answer with a SQLFiddle that proves that it has to somehow be the data. A join does not mess up setting a variable....

Comment: Wow.  I feel like an idiot.  I was passing bad data to the stored procedure.  *sigh*.  6 hours trying to track down the problem, and it was a problem with my app.  I'm going to go cry now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your code should works because of `WHERE` clause. IMO line:

```
   where dtxr.QEI = @p_QEI
```

should looks like:

```
   where x.QEI = @p_QEI
```

My second hint, please check `@p_QEI` variable, does it contain the proper value?